# Particular implementation of Python Descriptors

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

```
class Cls():

    def __init__(self, start):
        self.value = start


    class Desc():
        def __get__(self, instance ,owner):
            print("In Descriptor's __get__method")
            return self.value
        def __set__(self, instance, start):
            print("In Descriptor's __set__ method")
            self.value = start

    value = Desc()

X = Cls('Hello')
X.value = "Hi"
```

Above implementation of descriptor is obscure for me. X.value and Cls.value are refering to same object and is of class str. but Cls.__dict__['value'] is descriptor object. There are two types assigned to a name 'value'.

Can somebody explain this?. What is the logic behind this particular implementation. Why Cls.value or X.value is not descriptor object. I am using python 3.3

Comment: Do you understand how the descriptor protocol works?  Because what you're describing sounds like exactly how it's designed to work.  The descriptor protocol is activated when you do `obj.value`.  It is not activated when you do `obj.__dict__['value']`.

Comment: It means there is 'value' which is refering to string object "hello" in Cls namespace. Then there is another 'value' refering to Descriptor object that too in Cls namespace

Comment: You have a misunderstanding.  `self` inside your `__set__`/`__get__` methods refer to the descriptor object itself, not to the `Cls` instance.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing things by using the name `value` for two things: one is an attribute of `Cls`, and its value is a descriptor object.  The other is an attribute of that descriptor object, and that is the one whose value is the string.

The key thing to remember is that there is only *one* descriptor object, shared across all instances of the class.  When you do `self.value = start` in your `__set__` method, `self` refers to the descriptor object, so you are setting a "value" attribute on the descriptor object itself, not on the `Cls` instance.  (If you change it to `instance.value = start` instead, you will get a recursion error, since that will try to call `__set__` again.)

You will see what is going on if you create multiple instances of your class:

```
>>> x = Cls("oops")
In Descriptor's __set__ method
>>> y = Cls("dang")
In Descriptor's __set__ method
>>> x.value
In Descriptor's __get__method
'dang'
>>> Cls.__dict__['value'].value
'dang'
```

Notice that creating `y` changed `x.value`.  This is because there is only one descriptor object, and it only has one "value" attribute, so that value is shared across all instances of `Cls`.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here, so it's hard to say how to "fix" this.  Some general principles are:

1. Don't use `self` in `__get__` and `__set__` unless you want to store class-level information.  To store instance-specific data, you need to use `instance`.
2. Even if you do the above, don't use the same name for the descriptor attribute itself and the hidden attribute where it stores its data, or you will step on your own toes.
3. Unless you want to do something really fancy, you probably can just use `property` and not write your own descriptor at all.  If you "fixed" the descriptor you wrote above, it would still be useless, because it wouldn't do anything that `property` doesn't already do.

Comment: You are right the usage of value created confusion. Further storing values in descriptor object namespace created more confusion. I got it

Comment: One more concern I have is (may be its a design issue) why type(Cls.value) is of class str. Shouldn't it be of Descriptor object

Comment: Typing `Cls.value` is going to evaluate to `Cls.__dict__['value'].__get__(None, Cls)`. If that returns a string, then the type will be `str`. It will never be the descriptor (unless your `__get__` returns itself).

Comment: @user634615: The whole point of descriptors is that when you access them you don't get the descriptor itself, you get the result of calling the descriptor's `__get__`.